# Parsing issue with 2 different export default

Tags: reactjs, pagination

I am currently working on a project and I wanted to put in pagination in my Application to make it where I can keep adding products in the database, and I've come into an issue with my coding.

What am I doing wrong and what is the best work around for this solution? Keep in mind that I've already have imported my useState and useEffect in the 'react'.

```
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode/posts';

export default function ProductApp() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) return response.json();
      throw new Error('opps, something did not work right');
    })
    .then ((products) => setProducts(products))
    .catch((error) => setError(error.message));
  }, []);

    if (error) return <h1>{error}</h1>
};

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  
      this.state = {
        loggedInStatus: "NOT_LOGGED_IN",
        user: {}
      };
  
      this.handleSignIn = this.handleSignIn.bind(this);
      this.handleUnsuccesfulLogin = this.handleUnsuccesfulLogin.bind(this);
      this.handleSignOut = this.handleSignOut.bind(this);
    }
  
    handleSignIn() {
      this.setState({
        loggedInStatus: "LOGGED_IN"
      });
    }
    
    handleUnsuccesfulLogin() {
      this.setState ({
        loggedInStatus: "NOT_LOGGED_IN"
      });
    }

    handleSignOut() {
      this.setState ({
        loggedInStatus: "NOT_LOGGED_IN"
      });
    }
    
    checkLoginStatus() {
      return axios
        .get("http://localhost:3001/logged_in", 
          { withCredentials: true })
            .then(response => {

              const loggedIn = response.data.logged_in;
              const loggedInStatus = this.state.loggedInStatus;

              if (loggedIn && loggedInStatus === "LOGGED_IN") {
                return loggedIn;
              } else if (loggedIn && loggedInStatus === "NOT_LOGGED_IN") {
                this.setState ({
                  loggedInStatus: "LOGGED_IN"
                });
              } else if (!loggedIn && loggedInStatus === "LOGGED_IN") {
                this.setState({
                  loggedInStatus: "NOT_LOGGED_IN"
                });
              }
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log("Error", error);
            });
    }
  
    componentDidMount() {
      this.checkLoginStatus();
    }
  
    handleLogout() {
      this.setState({
        loggedInStatus: "NOT_LOGGED_IN",
        user: {}
      });
    }
  
    handleLogin(data) {
      this.setState({
        loggedInStatus: "LOGGED_IN",
        user: data.user
      });
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
          <Home />
        <Switch>
          <Route
                exact 
                path={'/'}
                render={props => (
                  <Main
                    {...props}
                    handleSignIn={this.handleSignIn}
                    handleSignOut={this.handleSignOut}
                    loggedInStatus={this.state.loggedInStatus}
                  />
                )}
                />
          <Route path='/products' component={Products}/>
          <Route path='/contactus' component={ContactUs}/>
          <Route path='/signup' component={SignUp}/>
          <Route path='/signin' component={Login}/>
          <Route
                exact
                path={"/signin"}
                render={props => (
                  <LogOut
                    {...props}
                    loggedInStatus={this.state.loggedInStatus}
                  />
            )}
          />
          {/* <Route path='/profile' component={Profile}/> */}
        </Switch>
      </Router>   
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can't do 2 or more default exports in a single file.**

What you can do is, you can have a `default export` and rest as `named exports`.

---

Default exports are exported as

```
export default function(){}
```

and imported as

```
import App from "./App.js"
```

---

Named exports are exported as

```
export function App(){}
```

and imported as

```
import {App} from "./App.js"
```